# Is there a way to execute function once per submit in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I have a simple form submit in Svelte and its using Bootstrap validation to display the error. For example, I have email and password fields, and if I leave those empty then click the submit button, the error message will be displayed.

I want to make the error message disappear when user start typing so I write an event like so:

```
on:input={$form.clearErrors('email')}
```

It is working and all, but the event will be triggered everytime user input anything in the email field. I want to make it fire only once for every submit.

I tried this code but it doesn't work the way I wanted to:

```
on:input|once={$form.clearErrors('email')}
```

Is there any way I can make the event fire only once everytime user click a submit button? Like, the event is fired only once, but when the user clicked the submit button, those event is available again.

Comment: Both code snippets are identical and missing a `() => ...`?

Comment: @H.B. Oh sorry I pasted the wrong code. I've updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone might be in the same situation and need an answer, here's how I've finally done it:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control form-icon-input {$form.errors.email ? 'is-invalid' : ''}" id="email" bind:value={$form.email} on:input={$form.errors.email ? $form.clearErrors('password') : ''}>
```

When user start inputting, check whether the current input has error or not, if it has error, then execute the clearErrors function. If not, do nothing.

Well in the end the checking part will always be done when user's typing. But I guess it's still better than executing clearErrors function over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You could set an error flag variable that is set to true when errors are detected on submit button click. When input is detected it clears errors only if error flag is true.

```
const handleInput = () => {
   error = false
   $form.clearErrors('email')
}
```

```
{#if error} on:input = {handleInput} {/if}
```

Comment: But how to put that inside <input> tag?

I tried to do so but got an error:

<input type="email" class="form-control form-icon-input {$form.errors.email ? 'is-invalid' : ''}" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com" bind:value={$form.email} {#if error} on:input = {handleInput} {/if}>